# Which Cleistocactus might this be?

Tags: cactus

I purchased this beauty a short time ago and have been unable to ID it as yet. Anyone know which cactus this is?

[image: Cactus Pic]
Here is a photo of the top which looks like the Epostoa Lanata
[Top View Pic http://Selva.Cabal.mx/Pic5.jpg](http://Selva.Cabal.mx/Pic5.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's Espostoa lanata, though I can't really tell if there's a bit of a tuft at the top - the top view of a cactus is quite important for ID purposes, but there's a pic here
http://www.cactus-art.biz/schede/ESPOSTOA/Espostoa_lanata/Espostoa_lanata/Espostoa_lanata.htm

Comment: I added a top view which seems to verify your suggestion, what do you think

Comment: @RichardCouture yep, I reckon so...

Comment: Seems to match E. lanata. I'm confused though, is that a name label just to the left of the plant? The O. macrodysis to the right is labeled.